# Check variable equals a certain number

Tags: php, validation, if-statement

I need to check to make sure a variable equals either 5, 10, 50 or 100. If it doesn't then I want to set it to 5. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this IF statement?

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['number']) && $_REQUEST['number'] !== "5" || $_REQUEST['number'] !== "10" || $_REQUEST['number'] !== "50" || $_REQUEST['number'] !== "100") {
  $number = 5;
} else {
  $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to break up your logic to overcome [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). When in doubt, use parenthesis.

I also inverted the logic. It reads more naturally.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['number']) && ($_REQUEST['number'] == "5" || $_REQUEST['number'] == "10" || $_REQUEST['number'] == "50" || $_REQUEST['number'] == "100")) {
  $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
} else {
  $number = 5;
}
```

While the above works, you could also streamline it with something like [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
isset($_REQUEST['number']) && in_array($_REQUEST['number'], array(5, 10, 50, 100))
```

Comment: "isn't 5 OR isn't 10 OR isn't 50 OR isn't 100" is *always* true.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST['number']) && ($_REQUEST['number'] == "5" || $_REQUEST['number'] == "10" || $_REQUEST['number'] == "50" || $_REQUEST['number'] == "100")) {
  $number = $_REQUEST['number']; 
 } else {
   $number = 5;
 }
```

Comment: Nope, he said, if its NOT 5,10, 50 or 100, then set to 5.

Comment: His written login is inverted in comparison to his coded logic.

Comment: Problem: what if `isset($_REQUEST['number'])` is false?

Comment: @GigaWatt: Then, the following check is immaterial. The whole question matters only when `$_REQUEST['number']` (the variable that needs to be checked) is set

Answer (score 1):

You've got some very confusing code. Does nothing you said you wanted.

this should be it:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['number']) && in_array($_REQUEST['number'], array(5, 10, 50, 100))) {
    $number = (int) $_REQUEST['number'];
} else {
    $number = 5;
}
```

Combined from other answers so thank everyone :)

Comment: You should probably make `in_array()` compare strict (set third parameter to `true`) and have the haystack be an array of strings. If you don't do this, then when `$_REQUEST['number']` equals `"10F"`, for instance, it would pass as well. Other than that, good solution.

Comment: Are you sure about that? If so, we could also set the type to integer. - EDIT: checked and changed. Thanks! You learn something every day :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap things around a bit:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['number']) || ($_REQUEST['number'] !== "5" && $_REQUEST['number'] !== "10" && $_REQUEST['number'] !== "50" && $_REQUEST['number'] !== "100")) {
  $number = 5;
} else {
  $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
}
```

Narration of the above: if number isn't set, make it 5.  If it is set, but isn't 5, 10, 50, or 100, set it to 5.  Otherwise, leave it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier in the long run to break the logic up into a different format to try to be a bit clearer, rather then having a single 'if' statement.

```
$acceptable = array(5, 10, 50, 100);
$number     = null;

if (isset($_REQUEST['number']) {
    $number = intval($_REQUEST['number']);
}

if (!in_array($number, $acceptable)) {
    $number = 5;
}
```

But with keeping it as a single if statement:

```
if (
    isset($_REQUEST['number']) && (
        $_REQUEST['number'] === "5" ||
        $_REQUEST['number'] === "10" ||
        $_REQUEST['number'] === "50" ||
        $_REQUEST['number'] === "100"
    )
) {
  $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
} else {
  $number = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although [iMoses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13313364/165154), and others already laid down the basics of simplifying your routine, I would suggest making the `in_array()` check more strict. If you don't and `$_REQUEST['number']` would, for instance equal `'10F'`, it would also pass.

```
// I like to define default values up front.
$number = 5;

// since $_REQUEST['number'] should always be a string
// make in_array() check strictly against these string values
$allowedNumbers = array( '5', '10', '50', '100' );

// make in_array check strictly
if( isset( $_REQUEST['number'] ) && in_array( $_REQUEST['number'], $allowedNumbers, true ) )
{
    // get proper integer value
    $number = intval( $_REQUEST['number'] );
}

var_dump( $number );
```